# Context Menu on Android WebView

Tags: android, contextmenu, webview

I'd like to add a context menu on an entire Android WebView. I have the following code:

```
registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.webview));
...
public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
   if (v.getId() == R.id.webview) {       
       //display context menu
   }
}
```

I noticed that the context menu is only displayed when a long press is done on a link in the webpage rendered by the WebView. When a long press is done in an empty area of the web view (an empty or text only area of the web page) the context menu is not displayed.

Any idea about how to display a context menu for the entire webpage and not only for links?

Comment: are you testing this on the emulator or an actual dev phone?

Comment: testing on both, emulator and nexus one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Take a look at onLongClick() and then implement on your dialog with a list.

Comment: I got the same problem, and I added onLongClick listener. However, my onLongClick doesn't get hit. Any idea why?

Comment: onLongClick() method is not working for Android os version 4.1