# Android WebView: how to make context menu work for text area?

Tags: android, webview, contextmenu

It's straightforward to add context menus to the webview. However, by default, the menu popups up only when you click a link or an image, but not on regular text area.

I found this [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211980/context-menu-on-android-webview) suggesting to add onLongClick to the activity, but I tried it and it doesn't get hit at all.

//---------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT:

I got a hint from a related question that I have to subclass webview and override some functions. I seem to get the context menu working. However, the webview doesn't behave normal. In particular, I can't scroll the view anymore. I guess I just miss something. Your help is much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {
    WebViewerActivity _activity;
    Context _context;
    GestureDetector _gd;

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
        this._context = context;
        _gd = new GestureDetector(context, sogl);
    }
    public void setActivity(WebViewerActivity activity){
        _activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return _gd.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener sogl = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) 
        {             
            return true;         
        }          
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) 
        {             
            _activity.onLongClick(MyWebView.this);
        } 
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {         
        MyWebView.this.scrollBy((int)distanceX, (int)distanceY);
        return true;
    }
    };
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------

MORE EDIT:

Okay, I added override of onScroll to SimpleOnGestureListener as shown above, and it makes the webview scrolling work. However, the original scrolling of the webview bounces back automatically if you scroll it too far outside. However, this scrolling doesn't have this nice feature. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the onLongClickListener with the WebView instead. The view might be consuming the event and not passing it back to the Activity. I assume the currently working menus are created by registering the WebView using Activity.registerForContextMenu() ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, I tried that too and it doesn't get hit either. Yes, my context menus are created through Activity.registerForContextMenu(webView).